# random function generate 2 long string the same, is it bad luck or rand() is not random?

Tags: php, random

I came across a weird problem today with the RAND() function. 
I have written a session management class that generate a random session id using this function that I wrote

```
private function generateSessionID($len = 40) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,-';
    $newStr = '';
    $maxLen = strlen($characters)-1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) 
        $newStr .= $characters[rand(0, $maxLen)];

    return $newStr;
}
```

The issue is that two random strings were generated in the same day which cause one user to login as someone else! How could this happen? Is there a simple steps behind rand() so it goes back and generates the same way all over again? What could caused it to generate the same thing all over again?

From doing some research I learned that using `mt_rand()` is much better than `rand()` and also I made a use of `str_shuffle()` so I switched the function to this

```
private function generateSessionID($len = 40) {
    $characters = str_shuffle('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,-');
    $newStr = '';
    $maxLen = strlen($characters)-1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) 
        $newStr .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $maxLen)];

    return $newStr;
}
```

Can some one please help me understand what could be the issue here? why two "40 characters" strings were generated at in a one day?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for uniqueness, not randomness. rand(1,2) *can* produce the same result when run at two different times! Use uniqid()

Answer (score 0):

Well, random is, indeed, random. Using random numbers won't guarantee you a unique 40 character string every time, the best it can do is give you a high probability that it won't generate the same string. It's a lottery of session ID's and someone just happened to have won the lottery that day.

If you want to keep your current generator, what I would do is generate the session ID, check to see if it's already been used, and if it has call the function again until you get a unique one. Or you could do something like generate your random ID, append a time stamp onto it, then hash it.